# Why jquery .html() does not accept jquery effect and how can i solve it

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 box with jquery effect and one box that created when i click "Click to create Jquery Box" 
my problem is when i create jquery box with .html() method new created box does not accept jquery effect like other html boxes

demo
http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/f9s6X/

HTML

```
    <h2>Click to Add JQuery Box</h2>
<div class="box">Html Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Html Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Html Box 3</div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

CSS

```
   .box{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:gray;
    color:white;
    float:left;
    border:medium blue solid;
    margin:10px;
   }
```

JQuery

```
$("h2").click(function(){
    $("#res").html('<div class="box">JQuery Box 4</div>');
});
$(".box").hover(function () {
$(this).css("color","red");},
function(){
$(this).css("color","white");
});
```

Comment: +1 for useful question. So many votes on answers. What are answers without the question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just bind the hover event to elements of the box class it will work on the elements that are in the DOM at that moment. It's not a live binding however. You need to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for that.

Example:

```
$("body").on('mouseenter', '.box', function () {
    $(this).css("color","red");
}).on('mouseleave', '.box', function(){
    $(this).css("color","white");
});
```

[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9s6X/4/)

Comment: +1. As a side-note for OP: If you want it much shorter, you can use this: `$("body").on("hover", ".box", function() { $(this).toggleClass("over"); });​` with a single additional CSS class: `.over{ color: red; }` Same result, less code , separated style definitions from code and CSS is easily changed without the risk of changing code.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl As of jQuery 1.8 using hover as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave" with on is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

Comment: @undefined: +1 Nice find. In that case I suppose I would have to change the shortened version to: `$("body").on("mouseenter mouseleave", ".box", function() { $(this).toggleClass("over"); });​`

Answer (score 3):

You would have to call `.hover` on the new box.  That new box didn't exist when it called it in the first place.

Alternatively, you can use [`.on` and a delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

The best alternative though if your use case is really as described in your question, [use the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslinks.html).

Comment: A demo for the technique posted by Brad using `.on()` - http://jsfiddle.net/f9s6X/3/

Comment: I Want Do it with JQuery not CSS

Comment: @afshin, Did you read my post?  I gave you several options.  techfoobar posted an excellent example.

Comment: As a side-note, you might as well use `on` instead of `hover`. Saves a lot of roundabouts. `hover` actually calls `mouseenter/mouseleave`. `mouseenter/mouseleave` are mapped to `mouseover/mouseout`. Finally `mouseover/mouseout` calls `on` anyway.

Comment: Just be careful about using `.on()` in a delegated manner when it isn't needed.  There is significant overhead with it, especially when your outside selector is something like `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like this :)
The trick is to put your code inside "click" function.

```
$("h2").click(function(){
$("#res").html('<div class="box">JQuery Box 4</div>');

$(".box").hover(function () {
$(this).css("color","red");},
function(){
$(this).css("color","white");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like it,

```
$("h2").click(function(){
    var $box = $('<div class="box">JQuery Box 4</div>')
      .hover(function () {
        $(this).css("color","red");},
      function(){
        $(this).css("color","white");
    });
    $("#res").empty().append($box);
});
```